# How can I write a function that expect a class as parameter with a private constructor

Tags: typescript

(playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6qgXigQgHcoAKAOmoENUBzJALigEFVUaQAeGhEAHwBKAgKgBvAL4BuAFCyAZugTYAloigBbEADFlaxNwAqAIRpJoEAB7AICACZJYiFBmy4B5MxZanzEEXFZKBCoVAhgdFQEKEwAG3MnGAALVTj7KGtbBydvaCDQwqgAemKoakpg0JlZSXl4xNgJKpDS8upa2UwXYFgAJgItXX1gdQRyGCE5LoSkJwBRZsKwVFUANxpbWJ63HFRyQJaitoqjurru5F75gcJtPRVRxHJ5qdkgA))

let's say I want to write a function that accepts a class as input (I am writing a mixin following the example in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#constrained-mixins)).

```js
type Constructor = new (...args: Array<any>) => {};

function myFunction<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
    return class Child extends Base {
        // ...
    };
}
```

I can use it with "normal" classes

```js
class C {
    // ...
}
const C2 = myFunction(C);
```

But the compiler gives me an error if I try to call `myFunction` on a class with a private constructor

```js
class E {
    private constructor() {
        // ...
    }
}
const E2 = myFunction(E);
```

with the error `Cannot assign a 'private' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.`

but how can I change `Constructor` (well, the type of `Base`) to say that "it should be subclassable" and that should accept also classes with a private constructor?

Comment: Could you try a construct signature that returns never? Just a thought, not at a computer at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. You can't extend classes with private constructors by design.

```js
class E {
   private constructor(): {}
}

class F extends E { } // Cannot extend a class 'E'. Class constructor is marked as private.
```

If your goal is to make it impossible to instantiate the class by a user, but only its children made with myFunction, you can ask for a protected constructor. Unfortunately, it can't be requested directly, so you have to do some hacky type inferring.

```js
abstract class ProtectedConstructorSource {
    protected constructor (...args:any[]) {};
} 

type ProtectedConstructor = typeof ProtectedConstructorSource;
type PublicConstructor = new (...args: any[]) => {};
type Constructor = ProtectedConstructor | PublicConstructor;
```

So, now you can pass a class with a protected constructor as an argument to myFunction. But instead of constraining it to `ProtectedConstructor` you have to constrain it to `Constructor` type. In this case, TypeScript will allow you to extend it.

```js
function myFunction<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase): PublicConstructor {
    return class Child extends Base {
        public constructor() {
            super();
            console.log("Hello! I am the child of the class with protected constructor");
        }
    };
}

class E {
    protected constructor() {
        console.log("Hello! I am a protected constructor.");
    }
}

const E2 = myFunction(E);
new E2();
```

Check it at [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgClA9hApvPgCYDCOAdpFAK7w5QDKONUs%20CA3gLABQCAhAAdcBIsSSVqdCAwQAKAHTLgUAOZgAXMAoBPANoBdAJRcAvgG4%20ZhHz4RdQjtjyECZKdBlyAvAgdOOABmWKJuJORUXvRMLGz4VrwBzjQgyACWsJHSMQh%20FPgA7grKiqoamgg6BiZ5AHzmickI2dGyUHmhruKttLkAPlipGVmefe2JfEE0FPDplAgAtroAYjNzlAA8ACoAQmgc%20AAeBBTEGL3eUHXy%202D4lXsHxpWYw5mXuTz8glD4EKwKEhUOgWgALdLICTHU7nBB3DjfQTI4TvWCSKLjBjyUxIlH4sA0JxQHGJfH42BSHDIfCKZA4NTyABEAAl8Mh6QBCBAASSqi38YI4sAhUIQwUFwpBGEK6QgYOEYXEGJy7SZxjJ5LMfGRlmsdl4KDQGAAolwdYIRN13Cq2tjcRaKVSaXSGcy2RycNy%20cABcBFdaSLasVBFOrNQJtbwo3xKVEECaAEydZZrWYQeYUeQmjV8ArFJOkvhAA).

Comment: thank you. I could change the constructor accessor to protected and apply your solution